# can't get a specific value from a 2d php array

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$descriptors = array(array ("science", "p1", "text"), array ("science, "p2", "more text")...array("Maths", "p1", "text"....)
```

I want to be able to get at the text for say the entry science, p2 - and I agree that the duplicate suggestion is useful, I don't think it works when you are looking to pull out one value for when there are many rows for each subject.

My question is 'how do I pull out 1 specific row which a particular value of subject and grade?
Any ideas please

Comment: You know this isn't even valid code? And what do you mean you can't upgrade from php 4.12 ? How old is this code even ?

Comment: [This PHP Array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) example might be of use to you.

Comment: thanks for your kind and helpful 'help' Daan. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
<?php
$descriptors = [
    'science' => [
        'p1' => 'text',
        'p2' => 'more text'
    ]
];
var_dump($descriptors['science']['p2']);
```

For an extremely old php version your'd have to use that variant:

```
<?php
$descriptors = array(
    'science' => array(
        'p1' => 'text',
        'p2' => 'more text'
    )
);
var_dump($descriptors['science']['p2']);
```

The output for both variants obviously is:

```
string(9) "more text"
```

---

And, BTW, PHP 4.12 is so old that most people don't even remember the syntax any more. Do yourself a favor and *do* upgrade to a current version. Alone the fact that this will close countless security issues should be worth the effort.

Comment: yes, I know its old. I'll have to find out what is on the school's internal server and see if its possible. But thanks for the tip

Comment: This smells a bit as if the whole system did not receive any updates and fixes for many years. In that case it can only be called a huge security risk for your whole organization. You really want to take it offline NOW.

Comment: Had a play with your answer - I think you have a much better way of arranging the array(s) - so I am going to rework into your suggestion.